# How can I save a picture on SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, image

I know it can be with a field 'image' on my table or the route something like 0x0002346sfh.. I rather to learn how to save the image with the route because I guess the database would be much faster that way, does anyone know the query to do this? Because I don't want to create a project in visual basic just to save a picture in my database I want to do this with a query if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

On Sql Server 2008 you can save an image in a field with type `image` or `varbinary`.

I advice you to use `varbinary` because `image` is deprecated.

To save in this field you must write a procedure to launch an INSERT/UPDATE statement.

Comment: can you write an example of the sintaxis to insert an image?

Comment: the query is simple INSERT INTO table VALUES (...) but you must convert your input image in a format readable by DB (using VB or another programming language)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable (id int, [image] varbinary(max) ) 

INSERT INTO ImageTable ([image])
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\Scenario1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) image;
```

Comment: and how is the sintaxis if I want to save an image in just one field using something like: "where id=3" ?

Comment: You Can try something like  this                                                          Update A set a.[image] = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\Scenario2.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) image)
 from ImageTable a
 where id = 1